# How to show that $v \mapsto \pi(f)v$ is differentiable?

Tags: representation-theory, lie-groups, automorphic-forms

Let $G$ be a compact group. Let $(\pi, V)$ be a representation of $G$ and $f$ a smooth function on $G$. Define 
\begin{align}
\pi(f)v = \int_G f(x)\pi(x) v dx.
\end{align}
We have 
\begin{align}
& \pi(y)\pi(f)v \\ 
& =  \int_G  f(x)\pi(x) v dx \\
& = \int_G  f(x) \pi(y) \pi(x) v dx \\
& = \int_G  f(x) \pi(y x) v dx \\
& = \int_G  f(y^{-1}x) \pi(x) v dx.
\end{align}
Why this implies that $v \mapsto \pi(f)v$ is differentiable? Thank you very much.

Comment: Isn't $v\mapsto \pi(f) v$ linear?

Comment: What kind of representation of $G$ is $(\pi,V)$ ? finite ? infinite ? over $\mathbb C$ ?

Comment: I'd wager there's some misunderstanding here... or garbling of language somewhere... because this _might_ have been a question about why the proof of Garding's theorem succeeds in showing that smooth vectors of a repn are dense... but, as it stands, as @JohnMa notes, $v\to \pi(f)v$ is a linear map... Is the question really meant to be "why is $\pi(f)v$ a smooth vector?"?